# Use a Docker container as an install set

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm currently building a Docker container that contains all the libraries needed for deployment of our app on a test machine, such as, for example, OpenCV 3.3 built with CUDA 9.

So, on a clean minimal OS install we can download the container and fire up our app in the desired environment, which is as I understand it one of the main reasons to use Docker.

So, after a while we decide to do our tests on the bare metal without the Docker file system, etc, in the way. Can we somehow replay the `Dockerfile` commands or image command history to run the `apt-get`, etc of not just the current package, but all `FROM` packages that are not yet installed on the raw environment?

Comment: Something like `docker image history --no-trunc <your_image>`?

Comment: Sort-of, but with an intelligent reapplying of the commands so they don't trash the current system.